# Passing model from view is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

I'm obviously doing something daft here....

I have a view which displays some information (purely for display there's no data collection going on) with a continue button which when clicked should post the model being displayed back to the controller but the model is virtually always empty. An example being:

```
<p>Analysis Code: @Html.DisplayTextFor(m=> m.SFCode)</p>
```

Which passes a null value back to the controller (although it does display correctly on screen) but if I use:

```
<p>Analysis Code: @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.SFCode)</p>
```

Then the value is passed back to my controller but it displays in a textbox on the view which I don't want.

So basically I just want to display some 'stuff' and pass this 'stuff' back to the controller but I can't find a helper method that displays as I want and pass it in.

Could someone show my the light please?

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()) // Creates <form>
{
    <p>Analysis Code: @Html.DisplayTextFor(m=> m.SFCode)</p> 
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SFCode)
}
```

Add this into your form, it should work.

In order to POST your data back to the `Controller`, you need it to be inside an input field right? In this case a hidden input field fits your need.

Comment: Cheers bud, that works :) Your edit makes sense now! You're a star

Comment: Easy, right click that page and view source... you should understand what is happening... it is basic HTML, if you know how HTML post work you will understand it.